# Choosing object field by method argument

Tags: java

I have a problem. I want to choose object field by method arguments. For example:

```
public class Company{
    String employeeName;
    String employeeSurname;
...

void method(XXX){
    Company.XXX
```

and if I would type method(employeSurname) i could do operations on employeSurname. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Just rename the method to `methodWithEmployeeSurname`

Comment: But I want have one method for every String fields for example. Not different methods for every fields.

Comment: I think you need to describe a little bit more about what you're trying to accomplish. That's a fairly strange requirement to have. Using reflection here is only going to give the possibility for bugs and runtime errors.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, OP is looking for something along the lines of what PHP does, using the double-$$, so if you had a $var = "method" and you did $$var() it would execute method();  Bad in PHP, and reflection in java only does part of what OP is looking for.  Agreed on the potential for bugs and RT errors.

Comment: Possible, probably, recommended, probably not.  You risk a lot of issues, not the least of losing encapsulation.  It's the `Company`'s responsibility to manage its values, your approach makes it possible for anybody to modify these values unchecked - this is just my opinion, but it's not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it using reflections. So do it like that:

```
public class Company{
    String employeeName;
    String employeeSurname;
...

String getStringField(Object obj,String fieldName) throws Throwable{
    Field f=Company.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return (String)f.get(obj);
}
```

You may read more about Reflections at the following site: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/